# IPv6 Neighbor Solicitation

Tags: ipv6

rfc2461 states that
"Nodes send Neighbor Solicitations to request the link-layer address of a target"
Therefore the sending node derives the solicited-node multicast address from the target nodes IPv6 address.

What I do not understand: 
If a node knows the IPv6 address it simultaneously knows the link-layer address (since the link-layer address of the respective node is included in the interface identifier part of the IPv6 address).

Example: Node A want's to send a message to Node B. 
Only the IPv6 address from Node B is known, link-layer address is unknown.

The interface identifier part of the IPv6 address in this example is 5120:12FF:FE51:7210

Since the fourth octet is FF and the fifth octet is FE the sending node could assume that this must be an IEEE 802.3 MAC address.

It uses the first 24 bits and the last 24 bits of the interface identifier and inverts the seventh bit and consequently gets the IEEE 802.3 link-layer MAC address: 5320:1251:7210

For me there seems to be no reason to send a Neighbor Solicitation message to learn the Link-Layer address since the link-layer address can be derived from the IPv6 address. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Link-local addresses do NOT necessarily embed the MAC address. One could also conceivably use a EUI-64 link-local address based on a different MAC address than the one present on the adapter.

Comment: And if the fourth octet isn't FF, what can it then assume? RFC4941 assigns other addresses, and that's what my laptop uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  the MAC address in the IPv6 address is avoided due to privacy reasons. If the ipv6 address uses EUI-64/MAc address, this can help a server to track the user even if he changes the ISP. For this reason, newer OS like windows 7 has feature to enable random address as identifier & its enabled by default.